# PHP functions as variables

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

When I do something like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO something (something) VALUES('".$something."')");  
if($query){
//do stuff
}
```

or

```
$mailstuff = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if($mailstuff){
//do stuff
}
```

Which part of the code actually executes the function? The `if` or the declaration? References appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mailstuff = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

if($mailstuff) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Here is what will be done (in the correct order) :

- `mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)`
- The `mail` function has returned something. This something is assigned to `$mailstuff`.
- The `if` statement will check if the something in `$mailstuff` is somewhat equal to `true`

Please not that contrary to what you suggest in your comment, the server will parse all the code before actually executing it.

Comment: i guess i should look up the definition of the word "parse". Thanks

Comment: The parsing will construct a tree of the source code that the computer can understand. The engine will then execute it. Between the two of them, a compiler can convert the tree to bytecode to speed up the execution. That's not very important in the original question, just nice to know :)

Answer (score 4):

Explanation in the code...

```
$mailstuff = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
             ^-----------------------------------^
            /*  This part executes the function */


if($mailstuff) {
  ^----------^
/* Condition Here Checks whether the function is successfully executed */
//do stuff
}
```

[**PHP function() Reference**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)

Comment: @WesleyMurch Actually but he needs some reference, I thought he might take a look how functions actually work

Comment: So, I'll assume the server parses it on the first occurrence? This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Adelphia It actually executes the code inside the function when you declare it...